# Open browser in Android Captive Portal after sign in

Tags: android, captiveportal

I am making a captive portal for Android:

1. the user connect to Wi-Fi
2. the captive portal open with informations for login (302 of /generate_204)
3. I post the informations and release the user to use internet (204 of /generate_204)
4. **THE PROBLEM**: the captive portal close and the browser not open

My purpose is - after the post the informations - release the user, close captive portal and open the browser.

How I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have tried every option (JavaScript, redirection, different answers for diffirent UserAgents) in every combination, unfortunately I have to conclude that that it isn't possible. 
(iOS is OK, you just need to window.open() on 4th step)

Comment: I have also lost LOT of time on it ... I cannot encourage people most to stop looking for this on android... on iOS is simple

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
private void CaptivePortalDetectionEnabled() {
    if (CaptiveChange.isChecked()) {
        Settings.Global.putInt(MainActivity.this.getContentResolver(), "captive_portal_detection_enabled", 1);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Captive portal detection is now " + state() + "\n 網路檢查服務已\"開啟\"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Settings.Global.putInt(MainActivity.this.getContentResolver(), "captive_portal_detection_enabled", 0);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Captive portal detection is now " + state() + "\n 網路檢查服務已\"關閉\"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

And you need the sign key of your mobile.